# Is any linear transformation with $\text{ker }(T)=\left\{\vec{0}\right\}$ an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm thinking no; for instance, $\exists \left\{\left.T:V\rightarrow W\right|  \text{Im }(T)\neq W\right\}$.

This seems counterintuitive, though. If such a $T$ with maximal rank exists, What would the target space $W$ look like?

Comment: Given $T: V \to W$ is it asking if $T$ is an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$, or between $V$ and $T(V)$? These questions (may) have different answers.

Comment: The question is: "Any linear transformation $T$ with $\text{ker }T=\left\{\vec{0}\right\}$ is an isomorphism - True or False"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T:V\rightarrow W$. If you have $\dim V = \dim W$, then yes, it is bijective (isomorphism), because of the following known theorem:

$$\dim V = \dim \text{Im } T + \dim \text{Ker } T$$

Which implies that $\dim W = \dim V = \dim \text{Im } T$ given that $\text{Ker }(T)=\left\{\vec{0}\right\}$, which shows surjectivity.

If $\dim V \neq \dim W$, though, there are many examples of injective transformations that aren't surjective, therefore aren't isomorphisms.

**EDIT:** As Travis mentioned in a comment, what I said only applies when $V$ and $W$ have finite dimension. If the dimensions are infinite, we can use a broader theorem (which implies the former theorem I mentioned), stated below:

$$\text{Im } T \cong V/\text{ ker }T$$

Where $V_1\text{ }/\text{ }V_2$ denotes the **quotient space** of $V_1$ over $V_2$.

A transformation is **injective** if and only if $\text{Ker }(T)=\left\{\vec{0}\right\}$, including the case of infinite dimension. It is **surjective** if and only if $\text{Im } T = W$. Therefore, if you study $V/\text{ ker }T$, you can decide if $T$ is bijective or not.

There will be examples in which you'll have bijectivity with infinite dimension, and examples like Travis' one:

$$R: (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) \mapsto (0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$$

in which you won't have bijectivity (only injectivity).

Comment: This argument only applies when $V, W$ have finite dimension. Consider the direct sum $\Bbb V := \Bbb R \oplus \Bbb R \oplus \cdots$ of countably many copies of $\Bbb R$. Then, the so-called right-shift operator $R: \Bbb V \to \Bbb V$ defined by $$R: (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) \mapsto (0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$$ is linear and injective (i.e., $\ker R = \{0\}$) but it is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the 0 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\{\vec{0}\}$. Consider the map $T(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$. Clearly this isn't bijective.

Answer (score 1):

No. A linear function is injective if, and only if, its kernel is $\{0\}$. It's easy to find examples where the surjectivity doesn't hold